# Fortran: Check namelist presence

Tags: fortran

As of now I am checking if iostat is smaller than 0 and re-open the file if a namelist could not be found (which is really ugly), i.e.:

```
read(100, nml=nm_tensor, iostat = ios)
if (ios < 0) then
    close(100)
    open(100, file="input_nm", status='old', action="read", iostat = ios)
end if
```

How do I check if a namelist is present in a file before reading it in? Is there a more elegant way for recovering when a namelist was not present and lead to an end-of-file error?

Comment: If the namelist wasn't present before you closed and re-opened the file, why should it be present afterwards? If you just wonder whether you have passed the namelist, you can `REWIND` it before reading the namelist.

Comment: In the first part of the question I would like to check the namelist's presence before reading it in altogether. This way I wouldn't throw any error, which would be even more elegant.
But `REWIND` was exactly what I was looking for in the second part of the question, thank you! :)

Comment: You can't find out if a namelist or anything else is present in a file before reading it.  To find out, something has to read it.  If another process is writing to the file, rewind will not help you unless the file is shared. Opening and closing may work if another process has written to the file.

Comment: Of course it would have to read the file, but maybe without influencing the current line number. Still, `REWIND` works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the file you're reading is:

```
&INT_NAMELIST
  A = 1,
  B = 2
/
&REAL_NAMELIST
  X = 3.15,
  Y = 2.71
/
```

Then the program

```
INTEGER :: A, B
REAL :: X, Y
NAMELIST /INT_NAMELIST/ A, B
NAMELIST /REAL_NAMELIST/ X, Y
OPEN(unit=100, action="READ", status="OLD")
read(100, nml=INT_NAMELIST)
read(100, nml=REAL_NAMELIST)
```

will work, but change the order of read statements, and it won't:

```
read(100, nml=REAL_NAMELIST)
read(100, nml=INT_NAMELIST)
```

because it has read past the `INT_NAMELIST` until it found and read the `REAL_NAMELIST`. If you are not sure of the order of namelists in the file, you should use a `REWIND` before every new namelist to be read, resetting the file position to the beginning of the file:

```
read(100, nml=REAL_NAMELIST)
rewind(100)
read(100, nml=INT_NAMELIST)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if a namelist exists is to add to the read statement the argument "END=XXX" where XXX is an integer error-label.  If the namelist is absent, control is switched to the line with the error-label.  This works for sure in the 2019 version of Intel Fortran and I think exists as a specification in Fortran 2003 if not Fortran 95.

Comment: If it uses labels, it is at least Fortran 90. The `end=` is surely older, because labels were old-fashioned already in 1990, but namelists themselves were standardized only in Fortran 90.

Comment: However, this end condition can be triggered also in some other circumstances.